# Unable to return a value from a linked database within stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, openquery

I'm trying to write a store procedure (or function if easier) to query a linked database and return a value but massively struggling. Any help greatly appreciated...

What I have tried:

```
CREATE Proc dbo.Sample (@FolderID as VARCHAR(50),
@FolderName varchar(50) OUTPUT)
AS
BEGIN

DECLARE @ParamaterDefinition NVARCHAR(500)
DECLARE @FolderNameRet VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @TSQL NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @TSQL = N'SELECT folder_name FROM OPENQUERY(LINKDB, ''SELECT 
        folder_name 
    FROM FolderTable
    where folder_id = '+ @FolderID +' and folder_status != 0'')'
SET @ParamaterDefinition = N'@FolderID as VARCHAR(50),
                    @FolderName VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT'
EXEC SP_EXECUTE @TSQL,
@ParamaterDefinition,
@FolderID,
@FolderName = @FolderNameRet output

SELECT @FolderNameRet AS "Output"
SELECT @FolderID AS "FolderID1"
SELECT @TSQL AS "Script"
SELECT @FolderName AS "FolderName1"
SELECT @ParamaterDefinition AS "Parameters"

RETURN @FolderNameRet 
END
```

Using the SELECT statements at the end to see each variable, and the script that is generated is fine and can run this separately to get my desired value. However @FolderNameRet is still coming up NULL.

I feel like the issue is me trying to return a value incorrectly but every method I have tried is failing.

i.e. Don't think I can set the return value within the dynamic script as this needs to be in a string format to run as part of the OPENQUERY statement. Also tried using `EXEC @FolderNameRet = SP_EXECUTE @TSQL` but this is also returning NULL.

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to assign value to @FolderName variable:

```
SET @TSQL = N'SELECT @FolderName = folder_name FROM OPENQUERY(LINKDB, ''SELECT 
        folder_name 
    FROM FolderTable
    where folder_id = '+ @FolderID +' and folder_status != 0'')'
SET @ParamaterDefinition = N'@FolderID as VARCHAR(50),
                    @FolderName VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT';
```

Also `RETURN` for stored procedure is for status `INT` not `VARCHAR(50)`.

Comment: Exactly what I was missing, thank you. Also needed to change `SP_EXECUTE` to `SP_EXECUTESQL`.